# Calculating the ratio between the average engine life expectancies

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-wrangling

I have a small R dataframe below containing cars made in Japan and in Mexico from 2006 to 2008. I need to calculate the ratio between the average engine life for the cars built in Japan and Mexico for each year. I am using dplyr and so far I have been able to group by year and place built.

However I am stuck in this part. Any idea how I can calculate the ratio between the average engine life for cars built in Japan and Mexico for each year?

Here is the code I used:

```
cars_df %>%
    group_by(year_built, place_built) %>%
    summarise(car,year_built,place_built, 
               avg_life_exp = mean(engine_life_expectancy))
```

[image: example dataframe]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After we create the 'engine_life_expectancy', do a `mutate`.  The `summarise` by default drop the last grouping column.  So, now, it is grouped by 'year_built', thus we can divide the `first` element of 'avg_life_exp' by the `last` or the second

```
library(dplyr)
cars_df %>%
     group_by(car, year_built, place_built) %>%  
     summarise(avg_life_exp = mean(engine_life_expectancy)) %>%
     mutate(ratio = first(avg_life_exp)/last(avg_life_exp))
```

NOTE: Instead of specifying 'car' in the `summarise` (as `summarise` from the new version can return multiple rows for each group), we can include the 'car' also as a grouping column

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried and it gives me the error: x object 'engine_life_expectancy' not found

Comment: # I changed the code replacing the engine_life_expectancy by avg_life_exp inside the mutate and it works. is it ok? 
cars_df %>%
  group_by(car, year_built, place_built) %>%  
  summarise(avg_life_exp = mean(engine_life_expectancy)) %>%
  mutate(ratio = first(avg_life_exp)/last(avg_life_exp))

Comment: @Kintaro sorry, a typo.  it would be `avg_life_exp` corrected